# Ubuntu Random Crashes

Tags: 18.04, google-chrome

I've been experiencing random crashes constantly since I've switched to Ubuntu.

It first started on Ubuntu 19 but thought I'd have less on 18 but it is still occurring, albeit less frequently.

I'm normally just using chrome but sometimes I'm doing web development and running a development server with chrome open.

I'm including the syslog, any help would be appreciated! Let me know if there's anything else I can provide.

System:
Huawei Matebook D Ryzen

logs and screenshots:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1vLbEzh-e05B9LYtOgvaGdVYrMPITd7Jx?usp=sharing

Comment: Your link is bad. Tell us more detail about your crashes. What do you see on the screen? Edit your question and show me `ls -al /var/crash` and `free -h`. What version Ubuntu right now?

Comment: @heynnema sorry for the delay. I reuploaded and included the requested information

Comment: You have probably installed a bad GNOME Shell extension. Please edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Place the results into your question, not via a screenshot. Edit, paste, select pasted text, click the {} icon to format the text, save.

Comment: @heynnema I might be doing something wrong cause I only see application_state in the gnome-shell folder

Comment: Sorry, we had a three day power outage here. You didn't look in the correct directory. Please review my `ls -al` commend and try again. Lets check your memory... go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This will take many hours to complete.